# JSON syntax error when running page in iFrame

Tags: javascript, json, iframe

I'm developing a website where users can book a table in a restaurant online. Everything's working fine, except one thing: When I put the reservation page in an iFrame on another domain, in a lot of browsers I get an error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)`. The `Network -> Response` tab in DevTools tells me, that response data could not be loaded because the request has been redirected.

This is the page that works well: https://dev.table4u.de/dimostrazione

Here I put the page in an iFrame for testing: https://www.restaurant-zukunft.de/iframe-test

This error comes up in a lot of browsers except Firefox, so could this be a problem with formatting the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a problem related to data. It's a problem with Chrome (and other browser). It is very strict when you use `iframe`. When you send POST request to `https://dev.table4u.de/index.php?option=com_tablebooking&task=search.getWorkingHours`, you can remark that cookie is not sent.

[image]

It's not the same for Firefox :

[image]

So, you're backend part think that the current client is not trusted so it redirects the link instead of given you the JSON that you expect.

Chrome (and other browser) avoid to send cookie because domain is changed due to `SameSite` policy (You can check on the internet what is it exactly). It expected `www.restaurant-zukunft.de` but you use `dev.table4u.de` on POST request. You can temporarly disable this behaviour on Chrome by changing the following flag.

[image]

You can found it on [chrome://flags/](http://chrome://flags/). But it's a very bad idea to do this. In your case, try to use same domain. Or avoid to use iframe if possible.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Now I know where the problem occurs (never thought it had something to do with the session cookie) and I can try to do a workaround.

Comment: @steveac77 You're welcome :)